Encoder-Style NN converging to constant value
I'm developing a neural network for a physical simulation which basically boils down to taking in a sequence of 3x3 matrices (representing some physical quantities) and outputting another sequence.
I first tried doing it specifically for the case where the sequence length is 9, in which case I just flattened the whole array and fed it to a multilayer perceptron and it was working fine.
However, now I'm trying to expand to larger sequences, and since the matrices can affect each other I decided to use the attention mechanism. Essentially, I'm flattening each 3x3 matrix into a 9x1 vector during preprocessing and then putting it through an attention layer first before going through a feedforward network. Here's how my model looks right now (I'm using PyTorch):
class miniTransformer(nn.Module):

    # initialize neural network layers
    def __init__(self, num_heads = 1, dim_feedforward = 32, dropout = 0.1):
        super().__init__()
        self.attention = nn.MultiheadAttention(embed_dim=9, num_heads=num_heads, batch_first=True, dropout=dropout)
        self.MLP = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(9, dim_feedforward),
            nn.GELU(),
            nn.Linear(dim_feedforward, 9),
        )
        self.norm1 = nn.LayerNorm(9)
        self.norm2 = nn.LayerNorm(9)
        self.dropout1 = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.dropout2 = nn.Dropout(dropout)
    
    def forward(self, src):
        # run through attention heads
        src2, _ = self.attention(src, src, src)
        src = self.norm1(src + self.dropout1(src2))

        # run through multilayer perceptron
        src2 = self.MLP(src)
        src = self.norm2(src + self.dropout2(src2))
        return src

and here are my hyperparameters (batch size is 64):
# instantiate model
model = miniTransformer(num_heads=1, dim_feedforward=128, dropout=0.0)
model.apply(init_weights)

# Loss function and optimizer
loss_fn = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=3e-4)

However, when I try to train the new model on my dataset, for some reason it keeps converging to a constant value (which I presume is the mean). My dataset has 100K input/output sequences and I was able to train the simple MLP on far less data, so I don't think that's the problem.
So far, I have tried:

standardizing the input sequences to have zero mean and unit variance
initializing weights using Xavier initialization to avoid vanishing gradients
clipping gradients to avoid exploding gradients

The only other thing I can think of is maybe there are not enough neurons in the network so should I add more alternating attention/MLP layers like in a transformer?
Other than that, I don't know what to do but my model is still converging to a constant value, so I would really appreciate your help!
Thanks

The principal issue is that your code omits any positional encoding, so the attention mechanism treats all 9-dimensional embeddings as an unordered set. This often leads to a constant output, since the network lacks temporal or sequential cues to distinguish each time step. Also, only a single attention layer plus a single MLP may be too shallow, so stacking multiple layers (and including position embeddings) typically resolves the constant-prediction problem.

Thank you for your response! As far as I am aware in the actual physics of the problem the order shouldn't matter, but I guess a positional encoding would help the model to capture the relationships better. Let me try your suggestions out and see how it goes.

Yes, it worked! I used a sinusoidal positional encoding and 3 attention/MLP layers stacked together and now the output varies with the input (and the loss decreased by an order of magnitude). Thanks for the help!
